# Userform contains Textbox and Checkbox intput to worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

The user can enter up to 10 members at once.

```
Column A will be "Team Number"
Column B will be "Number of Member" 
Column C will be "Member Name" 
Column D will be "Month Available" 
Column E will be "Number of Family Members Coming" 
Column F will be "Family Members"
```

I have trouble trying to input the userform values to the worksheet.

```
'inputValue
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim rStart As Long
    Dim rFirstEnd As Long
    Dim rLastEnd As Long
    RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        rMemberEnd = CLng(txtNoMember.Value)
        rMonthEnd = CLng(txtNoMember.Value)
        rFamilyMemberEnd = CLng(txtNoFamilyMemberValue)
        For rStart = 1 To rMemberEnd
            With Worksheets(“Sheet1").Range("A1")
                .Offset(RowCount + rStart, 0).Value = txtTeamNo.Text
                .Offset(RowCount + rStart , 1).Value = txtNoMember.Text
                .Offset(RowCount + rStart , 2).Value = Controls("txtMemberName”  & Format(rStart, "00")).Value
            For rStart = 1 To rMonthEnd
                With Worksheets(“Sheet1").Range("A1")
                    If Controls ("chkMonth”  & Format(rStart, "00")).Value = True Then
                        .Offset(RowCount + rStart , 3).Value = CLng(Right$(Controls("chkMonth”  & Format(rStart, "00")).Name, 2))
                        .Offset(RowCount + rStart , 4).Value = txtNoFamilyMember.Text
                    For rStart = 1 To rFamilyMemberEnd
                            With Worksheets(“Sheet1").Range("A1")
                                .Offset(RowCount + rStart , 5).Value = Controls("txtFamilyMember" & Format(rStart, "00")).Text
                            End With
                    End If
                End With
            End With
        Next
```

This is the input to the worksheet.
[image]

This is what the UserForm looks like

[image]

Comment: could you show us what your userform looks like?

Comment: I do not recommend the use of `CurrentRegion`. I might be giving you the trouble. however if not, as what mehow commented, please show how the data in your form is organized so we can figure out how to manipulate the transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built a UserForm similar to yours and named the controls on it accordingly

[image]

now, double clicked the command button and used this code

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim members As Long
    members = CLng(txtNoMember.Value)

    Dim family As Long
    family = CLng(txtNoFamilyMember.Value)

    Dim months As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 12
        If Controls("chkMonth" & Format(i, "00")).Value = True Then
            months = months + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Dim total As Long
    total = members * months * family

    Dim j As Long, k As Long, m As Long, n As Long

    For i = 1 To members

        For j = 1 To total / members
            ws.Range("A" & ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = CLng(txtTeamNo)
            ws.Range("B" & ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = members
            ws.Range("C" & ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Controls("txtMemberName" & Format(i, "00")).Value
            ws.Range("E" & ws.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = family
        Next j

        For j = 1 To months
            For m = 1 To family
                If Len(Controls("txtFamilyMember" & Format(m, "00")).Text) <> vbNullString Then
                    ws.Range("F" & ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Controls("txtFamilyMember" & Format(m, "00")).Text
                End If
            Next m
        Next j

        For j = 1 To 12
            If Controls("chkMonth" & Format(j, "00")).Value = True Then
                ws.Range("D" & ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = CLng(Right$(Controls("chkMonth" & Format(j, "00")).Name, 2))
                ws.Range("D" & ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Resize(family, 1).Formula = ws.Range("D" & ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula
            End If
        Next j

    Next i

    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

which produced

[image]

---

`Me.Hide` hides the form instead of unloading it. Therefore the data on the form should still be accessible from the Module's code.

In your mode you load the form like this

`UserForm1.Show`

and then when you're done fetching data from it (again, that's in the Module no under the button's event) you unload it

`Unload UserForm1`

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, I get the same output as you, but is a little different from what I wanted. I tried 4 Members, 2 Months, 5 Family Members and this is the Output [link](i.stack.imgur.com/kChPD.png), however this is the output that I wanted [link] (i.stack.imgur.com/SRpVz.png). How do I allow all the _Feb_ to output first for _John_, follow by all the _March_, then _Feb_ for _Peter_ follow by _March_ for _Peter_. Hope you could help :) And I would like to ask you about Me.Hide, what does it do?

Comment: @Gervina I have edited the code and it works just like you wanted it to work. Please accept answer if it was helpful:)

Comment: Thanks so much, it works the way I wanted. But could I ask you another questions, about the additional line you added in. Why for _Month_, you have to add another line of code, what does `.Resize` does?

Comment: @Gervina thanks for accepting the answer:) `.Resize` expands the range you want to fill with data/formulas. For example `Range("A1").Resize(10, 3).Formula = "=Rand()"` is the same as `Range("A1:C10")` it changes the size from `A1` to 10 rows down and 3 columns to the right.

Comment: You are welcome :) You are good in VBA, thanks a lot for your help and answering my doubts! :)

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask you regarding this line of code `If Len(Controls("txtFamilyMember" & Format(m, "00")).Text) <> vbNullString Then` if I did validation to check that all `txtFamilyMember` is not empty before inputting the data, do I still need this line? Cause I tried and it still works.

Comment: @Gervina They are two different validations. I imagine that the validation you do is there to check if the logic of the form makes sense - ie. user enters 5 family members are coming - but only provides two names - which breaks the logic ( this is what you are handling ). The above quoted line of code is required for the loop logic - instead of reserving room for the *empty* members the loop only considers the ones which are not empty. I think you should leave it as is :)